# React Native: How to Get ButtonGroup/Segmented Buttons Working as Text? Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native, text, react-native-paper, buttongroup

I'm trying to use Segmented Buttons for a session type (for a tennis application). The only available session types are:
Singles, Doubles, Rally, Practice, and only 1 type can be selected.
Relative Segmented Buttons is at the very bottom of this code.

So, using React Native Paper docs, I am using:
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/SegmentedButtons/

It does show up on the screen, but when I submit the form by sitting the Add or Save button, the app crashes with the error:
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.
I don't understand how to change the button group to text component? Can anyone help?

Tried wrapping Segmented Buttons in , same error.

Comment: Please, share the code you use. And maybe some screenshots to improve your question's details to get answer fastly.